# Javascript and Strange Numbers

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I am needing to increment any number, regardless of decimal places. The only custom function is `decimalPlaces()` which goes like this:

```
function decimalPlaces(num) {
  var match = (''+num).match(/(?:\.(\d+))?(?:[eE]([+-]?\d+))?$/);
  if (!match) { return 0; }
  return Math.max( 0, (match[1] ? match[1].length : 0) - (match[2] ? +match[2] : 0) );
}
```

So, then, for instance (in Node):

```
a = 2.11
> 2.11
places = decimalPlaces(a)
> 2
additive = Math.pow(10,places*-1);
> 0.01
a + additive
> 2.11999999999999997
```

It works for 90% of cases, but not this one. I know there is a way to use exponents to get in and out of this problem (multiply the number by 10^places and add 1), but I'm just curious--where is this weird floating point problem coming from in what appears to be some really simple math?

Comment: Math in JS is a bad time. It's the IEEE floating point implementation fail fest.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849101/laymans-explanation-for-why-javascript-has-weird-floating-math-ieee-754-stand

Comment: @captray "Math in JS is a bad time" --- not in JS but in every language when you deal with IEEE754 numbers.

Comment: @zerkms this is true. But I wouldn't recommend ever doing any important math in JS, the language itself is a fail fest.