Why is (1 + Number.MIN_VALUE) equal to 1?
I noticed that these evaluate to true:

(1 + Number.MIN_VALUE) === 1

Object.is(1 + Number.MIN_VALUE, 1)


From the documentation:

The Number.MIN_VALUE static data property represents the smallest positive numeric value representable in JavaScript.

My questions are:

Since Number.MIN_VALUE is nonzero, why does adding it to a given number not result in a different number?

What is the minimum value that can be added to a given number to result in a different number?



Interesting question! I don't have an answer from the top of my head, but I'd start by understanding how the numbers are represented. Precision of numbers get lower as you go further away from 0. Maybe already at 1 the precision is not enough to distinguish MIN_VALUE differences.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#number_encoding

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849101/laymans-explanation-for-why-javascript-has-weird-floating-math-ieee-754-stand

As the reason (1.) is the same for all languages that use ieee 475 you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317661/adding-smallest-possible-float-to-a-float

Does this answer your question? Is floating point math broken?

@derpirscher No, I'm aware that floating point math is weird. I was wondering specifically why Number.MIN_VALUE appears to be equivalent to zero in some cases. It is because of floating point weirdness, but is a different question.

For your questions:
For more reliable comparisons, due to the nature of internal floating point representation, you can to compare like this:


const x = 0.1, y = 0.2, expectedResult = 0.3;

function equalNumber(a,b) {
  return Math.abs(a - b) < Number.EPSILON;
}

console.log('===', x + y === expectedResult);

console.log('equalNumber', equalNumber((x+y), expectedResult));



For your second question, that number you're asking for is Number.EPSILON.
Please note that with increasing numbers, the precision does decrease so this is not a very reliable way of testing for equality. For more information, read @Amadan's answer, or read up on MDN.

Thanks! I just ran a little loop to find the smallest number I could add to 1, and sure enough the result was the same value as Number.EPSILON, which I wasn't aware of until now. let last = 0, test = 1; while (1 + test !== 1) { last = test; test /= 2; } console.log(last);

return (a - b) < Number.EPSILON; is not a general solution to compare floats.   How to compare floats always depends on the use case. Also adding Number.EPSILON to a number does not guarantee that it would change, nor is it the smallest number that would result in a change (that’s only true when added to 1)

@t.niese Feel free to provide a more precise, comprehensive  answer. I'm looking forward to that!


What is the minimum value that can be added to a given number to result in a different number?

I am not sure there is an elegant way to do this in JavaScript. Fortunately, the way floating point numbers are represented is the same in most programming languages, so we can find out the answer elsewhere. Python, for example, has a method that reports the next representable floating point number after the given one, in a given direction. (C does as well; Python really just binds to the C one.) So, the first floating point number after 1.0 (in the direction of positive infinity) is:
import math

math.nextafter(1.0, math.inf)
# => 1.0000000000000002

The smallest number that you can add to 1.0 to change it should be somewhere around half of the difference, because of rounding:
x1 = (math.nextafter(1.0, math.inf) - 1.0) / 2.0
x1
# => 1.1102230246251565e-16
1.0 + x1
# => 1.0

x2 = math.nextafter(x1, math.inf)
x2
# => 1.1102230246251568e-16
1.0 + x2
# => 1.0000000000000002

So x1 and x2 are neighbouring floating point numbers (i.e. there is no other floating point number between them), where one is too small to matter in addition to 1.0, and the other is just sufficient.
We can bring it back to JavaScript to confirm:


x1 = 1.1102230246251565e-16
x2 = 1.1102230246251568e-16

console.log(`1.0 + ${x1} = ${1.0 + x1}`)
console.log(`1.0 + ${x2} = ${1.0 + x2}`)



Because floating point numbers lose accuracy as they gain magnitude, "the minimum value that can be added to a given number to result in a different number" depends on the number: what works for 1.0 will not work for 100.0.
Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have nextafter method. The question Fast nextafter function in JavaScript has a couple of answers that claim to implement it, but I am not mathematically strong enough to vouch for their correctness.
From the above, it can also be seen that the smallest number that can be added to 1.0 to make a difference is not, in fact, Number.EPSILON, but just above half of it, and it is specific to the case of 1.0. Number.EPSILON is sufficiently large to change 2.0000000000000004, the next floating point number after 2.0:


n1 = 2.0
n2 = 2.0000000000000004

console.log(`${n1} + Number.EPSILON = ${n1 + Number.EPSILON}`)
console.log(`${n2} + Number.EPSILON = ${n2 + Number.EPSILON}`)



